# How to determine tcp client is connect or not in c++

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, tcp

I save all **IP** of clients/**socket**s that are connected and after that I want to know when I write something from server to client, whether a client in CONNECT status or not. When I use `Write` function, it is possible to send data from server to clients discarded because one or more clients may disconnect, connection will be closed and data don't send. My code is:

```
void *connection_determine(void *ptr){

  while (1) {

    putchar(x[0]);

    std::list<int>::iterator it;

    it=list_client_sockets.begin();


    while (it!=list_client_sockets.end()){
        printf("%d\t",*it);
        if (read(*it, x, 1) < 1) {
            cout<<"yes"<<endl;
            perror("Error on write to client socket!\r\n");
            fflush(stdout);
            fflush(stderr);

            close(*it);
            it=list_client_sockets.erase(it);
            --it;
            //return 0;
       }
      it++;

    }
    //printf("0x%02X ",x);
    fflush(stdout);

   } 
 }

 // function for read data from pipe and send it to clients
void *pipeRead_thread_func(void *ptr) {
  int fd_pipe = *((int *) ptr);
  while (1) {
    char x[1];
    if (read(fd_pipe, x, 1) < 0) {
        perror("Read Error");
        return 0;
    }
    putchar(x[0]);

    std::list<int>::iterator it;

    it=list_client_sockets.begin();


    while (it!=list_client_sockets.end()){
        printf("%d\t",*it);


        if (send(*it, x, 1,0) < 0) {
            cout<<"yes"<<endl;
            perror("Error on write to client socket!\r\n");
            fflush(stdout);
            fflush(stderr);

            close(*it);
            it=list_client_sockets.erase(it);
            --it;
            //return 0;
       }

      it++;

   }
    //printf("0x%02X ",x);
    fflush(stdout);

  }
}
```

Comment: You can't necessarily detect that a TCP connection is closed, you only find out when you try to send some data and it fails. You need to keep track yourself of which connections have failed in previous calls.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way a client decides if a connection is to be closed is check if it has timed-out, if it hasn't received any messages for a specified time it closes the socket.
You detect if a socket is open by trying to read from it, if it fails the socket is closed.  You can use Keep Alive messages to keep the socket open. 
You can use separate threads for socket status detection and/or keeping the socket alive.